# Append text to text area but set caret position to end of line

Tags: java, javafx, text, textarea, area

**Hi!**

I'm currently trying to build a terminal emulator using JavaFX, I'd like to append some text after "enter" is pressed.
This works so far, but the problem is, that after my text is appended, the caret position is set to the next line.

This is what I have so far:

```
   String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
   emulator.appendText(newLine);
   emulator.appendText(prefix);
   emulator.positionCaret(emulator.getLength());
```

I already tried moving `emulator.appendText(newLine)` or removing it completely, but it still put the caret into the next line.

How do I proceed to make it stop doing that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After enter pressed you want to stay at the end of current line? Do I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for the issue.

I didn't think about the usual event which is executed by the enter key.

All I had to do was to add a EventFilter onto the Text Area.

```
emulator.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
                if (ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {

                    //Get Command
                    //Count Rows
                    int rowCount = emulator.getText().split("\n").length;
                    System.out.println(rowCount);

                    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    emulator.appendText(newLine);
                    emulator.appendText(prefix);
                    emulator.positionCaret(emulator.getLength());

                    ke.consume();
                }
            }
        });
```

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Yes, this is the most appropriate thing to do. However, two remarks :
1) `KeyCode.ENTER` is a constant, so you can check `ke.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER` instead of `ke.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)`.
2) Replacing **if** loop by a **switch-case** is much performant in terms of runtime, especially when there is a lot of keys to manage in your event filter.

Comment: You don't need to take care of carrige return; There is not a single occurance of `\r` in the source code of `TextArea`. Furthermore you do not need to count the lines yourself by splitting the text. In fact this is suboptimal: Simply use `emulator.getParagraphs().size()` instead of `emulator.getText().split("\n").length`

Comment: Note you can use [`System#lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()) instead of querying the system properties directly.